# POSTMAN Laravel Must Be a Valid JSON string

Tags: json, laravel, postman

[image: THIS IS MY POSTMAN REQUEST BODY]

When I send DATA LIKE this IT shows

```
{
"errors": {
    "slides": [
        "The slides must be a valid JSON string."
    ]
}
```

}
This is MY LARAVEL Validation Request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'slides' => 'required|json',
        'description' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

How can I solve this problem and how can I validate if the user we are getting required keys in that JSON string or not?

Comment: Your entire request is JSON so slides are not actually a JSON string they get decoded to an array so your rule should be `required|array|min:1` or something like that

Comment: @apokryfos how can i validate if the entered slide input is whether required json with required Keys or not??

Comment: your entire request is a JSON request which Laravel decodes so do normal validation to the input as though it  was not JSON

Comment: @apokryfos okay like What should I do to check whether the user is entered the right keys(text/video_url)or not

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-arrays something like `'slides.*.title' => 'required'` should work (assuming the title is required)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229720/discussion-between-eager-to-learn-and-apokryfos).

Answer (score 0):

Your entire request is JSON so slides are not actually a JSON string they get decoded to an array so your rule should be `required|array|min:1` or something like that